# Why does a QullJS delta appear out of order?

Tags: javascript, typescript, quill

The delta that's generated looks like:

```
{"ops":[{"retain":710},{"insert":" yesterday, and she says—”\n“The clinic?","attributes":{"prediction":"prediction"}},{"delete":28}]}
```

My code is:

```
      const delta = new Delta()
          .retain(documentData?.prediction?.currentPosition)
          .delete(previousPredictionText?.length || 0)
          .insert(predictionText, { prediction: 'prediction' })

    console.log('delta', JSON.stringify(delta))

      quillEditor.updateContents(delta)
```

It looks like I should first `retain`, then `delete`, then `insert`, but the generated `delta` seems to do it in a different order. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is pretty much the same issue you have https://github.com/quilljs/delta/issues/12 they dont do it in steps, they all refer to current document.

In the link there is even a guide how to do this, `their way` https://quilljs.com/guides/designing-the-delta-format/

Comment: Super helpful. Thanks!